Configuring log4net in a shared library for a micro services architecture in an ASP.NET Core Web API
I am currently working with a micro services architecture in ASP.NET Core Web API, and I have a shared library that is used across all of these micro services. My goal is to leverage log4net as my logging solution, with an aim to update a dedicated 'logger' table in my database.
To facilitate maintenance and management, I am interested in centralizing the logging configuration within the shared library itself. This way, all the micro services can use a single, unified logging configuration, thereby enhancing consistency and reducing redundancy.
However, I am finding it challenging to locate a guide or tutorial that specifically addresses this scenario - configuring log4net for a micro services architecture with a shared library.
Does anyone have any experience with this, or could point me towards some relevant resources? Furthermore, if you could provide some example code illustrating this setup, it would be immensely beneficial.

Should I include the next assembly in each project or it enough in the shared only? (I know it must be in the top level of each service)
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch =true)]


The implementation of the logger in shared library


public class SharedLogger
{
    // Initialize the log4net logger
    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(SharedLogger));

    // Configure log4net (this is the part I'm unsure about)
    public static void Configure(string configFilePath)
    {
        // Code to configure log4net using the XML file at configFilePath
        // ...
    }

    // Methods to log messages at various levels
    public void Info(string message)
    {
        log.Info(message);
    }

    // Other methods (Debug, Warn, Error, Fatal)...
}


The integration with the micro service?


Configuring log4net within a shared library for a microservices architecture ensures logging consistency.
Begin by adding the log4net package to your shared library project. Then, create a static class in your shared library to encapsulate the log4net configuration and logging methods. This class should initialize the log4net logger and provide static methods to log messages at various log levels, such as Info, Error, Fatal etc.
For the configuration, you can use an XML file for log4net settings. This file should be included in the shared library and copy the log output on build.
In your static logger class, implement a method to read this configuration file using the XmlConfigurator.Configure method. Please make sure to call this configuration method from the startup of each of your microservice that plans to implement this shared library.
To integrate log4net with your microservices, add a reference to the shared library and invoke the logging methods provided by the static logger class whenever you need to log messages.
Make sure to set the log4net xml configuration file's properties to "Copy to Output Directory" so that it is included with your deployed application.
Hope this helps.

im consufing with the basic , can u provide example? where should i add the [assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch =true)]
, should i install log4net for each project?

Yes, you'll need to.. though main code logic can remain in shared lib
